# Qt renderText() functions bug - text crashes

Tags: c++, qt, qglwidget

I use `QGLWidget` to draw my Graphics in QT, and I need to render some text inside my widget.

The problem is after some time, it turns from:

[Fine version http://imageshack.com/a/img823/867/9ycf.png](http://imageshack.com/a/img823/867/9ycf.png)

to this:

[Bugged version http://imageshack.com/a/img842/1774/57zs.png](http://imageshack.com/a/img842/1774/57zs.png)

And my code looks like this:

```
glPushMatrix();
        qglColor(Qt::white);
        renderText(-29, 11.0, -8, "Tablica wyników", QFont("Arial", 12, QFont::Light));
        ...
glPopMatrix();
```

What's wrong with that code/function?

Comment: Please edit your code to be a self-contained example, so that we can try it out. This means: make a small `main.cpp` that has the entire code, and update your question. What is the exact qt version you're using?